# Remove old clock entries

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I'm clocking the time spent on daily tasks like email and for that I
have a "Daily Routine" TODO entry. Clocking in this task adds a new
clock line everyday, leading to a very populated CLOCK drawer. I'd like
to limit its size by either a maximum number of clock entries by
removing the older ones or better, removing the entries older than some
date. Ideally, I'd like to find a function that tidies the clock drawer of an entry, to be added to the clock-in or clock-out hook.

Any idea how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
(defun jc-org-clock-remove-old-clock-entries (n)
  "Remove clock entries whose end is older than N weeks in current subtree.
Skip over dangling clock entries."
  (interactive "nnumber of weeks: ")
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (org-map-tree
     (lambda ()
       (let ((drawer (re-search-forward org-clock-drawer-start-re (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree)) t))
         (case-fold-search t))
     (when drawer
       (let ((re org-clock-line-re)
         (end (save-excursion (re-search-forward org-clock-drawer-end-re (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree)) nil)))
         )
         (while (re-search-forward re end t)
           (skip-chars-forward " \t\r")
           (looking-at org-tr-regexp-both)
           (when (>= (/ (time-to-number-of-days (org-time-since (match-string-no-properties 2))) 7) (float n)) (kill-whole-line))
           ))))))
    (org-clock-remove-empty-clock-drawer)
    ))
```

It should work if your clocking uses either a specific :CLOCK: drawer or the default :LOGBOOK: drawer, according to the value of the org-clock-into-drawer variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `org-clock-remove-empty-clock-drawer`. It uses `org-map-tree` and a regular expression based on `org-clock-drawer-name` to find the `:LOGBOOK:` drawers.

You can use the same logic to get `point` to the start of `:LOGBOOK:` and then handle all `CLOCK:` entries on a line-by-line basis. To parse the timestamps, you can use `org-ts-regexp-both` and `org-element-timestamp-parser`. Afterwards, you can use `kill-whole-line` to get rid of the entry.

So in short:

1. Find the next `:LOGBOOK:` via `re-search-forward`
2. Go forward a single line
3. Check the start of the line.

   - If it starts with `:END:`, stop the clock handling for the current drawer
   - If it starts with `CLOCK:`, search for the next timestamp.

     1. If it's too old, remove the whole line with `kill-whole-line`.
     2. Otherwise continue to the next line
   - goto 3.

Comment: Thanks, those are very good pointers. I'll try and come up with something.